# Getting an average value from a multidim array in PHP

Tags: php, recursion, multidimensional-array

I have an array with child arrays that I'm trying to sum up a specific key/val pair, to produce an average.
It goes something like this:

Data:

```php
$producttypes = [
    [
        'id'   => 0,
        'name' => 'Product Type 1',
        'lot'  => [
            [
                'lotid'  => 0,
                'label'  => 'Lot 1',
                'sold'   => 1,
                'models' => [
                    [ 'modelid' => 0, 'cost' => 2000000, 'size' => 3400 ],
                    [ 'modelid' => 1, 'cost' => 2100000, 'size' => 3500 ],
                    [ 'modelid' => 3, 'cost' => 2200000, 'size' => 3600 ],
                ],
            ],
            [
                'lotid'  => 1,
                'label'  => 'Lot 2',
                'sold'   => 0,
                'models' => [
                    [ 'modelid' => 0, 'cost' => 2000000, 'size' => 3400 ],
                    [ 'modelid' => 1, 'cost' => 2100000, 'size' => 3500 ],
                    [ 'modelid' => 3, 'cost' => 2200000, 'size' => 3600 ],
                ],
            ],
            [
                'lotid'     => 2,
                'lot_label' => 'Lot 3',
                'sold'      => 1,
                'models'    => [
                    [ 'modelid' => 0, 'cost' => 2000000, 'size' => 3400 ],
                    [ 'modelid' => 1, 'cost' => 2100000, 'size' => 3500 ],
                    [ 'modelid' => 3, 'cost' => 2200000, 'size' => 3600 ],
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
];
```

I can have any number of Product types, lots within those product types, and models within those lots. Models can be repeated across different lots, but lots can't repeat over different product types.

I need to be able to get the average prices and size for any lots that are sold, or not sold.

I tried making a recursive function, but I suck. I'm able to drill down to the level I need to, to satisfy the condition (if sold = true or false), but I cant find a way to pull the cost or size from the same array.

```
function getAvgByKey_r($arr, $find, $col, $cond, &$count=0, &$sum=0)
{

    foreach($arr as $key=>$value) {
        if(is_array($arr[$key])) {
            getAvgByKey_r($arr[$key], $find, $col, $cond, $count, $sum);
        } else {
            if($key == $col) {      
                if($value == $cond) {
                    /*insert magic space wizard code here*/
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    if($count > 0) {
        return $sum / $count;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Where $arr is the main array, $find is the field i'd like to average out (ie size or cost), $col is the key i'm checking for (ie sold), and $cond is value I'm checking for (1/0). &$count=0 and &$sum=0 I think are needed to carry into the next iteration of the recursive function.

This is our most desperate hour. Help me Obi-Wan Kenobi. You're my only hope.

Comment: Do you understand what passing a function parameter by reference does? Using the sample data you provided, how are you calling this `getAvgByKey_r` function and what output are you expecting?

Comment: You're making this a lot harder than it needs to be. You don't need a recursive function, you just need nested loops.

Comment: I'd be calling getAvgByKey_r in a loop elsewhere in the page, possibly within a loop.
The sample data is a very stripped down original, but basically I would call the function like this:

getAvgByKey_r($producttypes, ‘cost’, ‘sold’, 1)
I want to get an average ‘cost’ from all lots that are sold.
Maybe I don't need the reference parameter, I was just using a recursive function I found somewhere else.

Comment: I agree I could simplify this by doing nested loops, but I wanted to use this function on other arrays, not all using the same structure, but having same key=>val pairs. In the end I may just do multiple simple functions instead of a complicated universal one.

Answer (score 0):

Since I couldn't seem to find a way to keep track of the index from parent array, I cant seem to pull averages from a multidim array with a condition. The only way to do it as how Don R suggested, and use nested loops.

Here's my solution:

```
function getAvg_r( $arr, $key, $col=NULL, $cond=NULL )
{
    $total=0;
    $count=0;
    foreach((array)$arr as $producttype_row=>$producttype_value)
    {
        if( is_array($producttype_value) )
        {
            if( array_key_exists( 'lots', $producttype_value ) )
            {
                foreach($producttype_value['lots'] as $lots_row=>$lots_value)
                {
                    if( array_key_exists( 'models', $lots_value ) )
                    {
                        foreach( $lots_value['models'] as $models_row=>$models_value)
                        {
                            // what we've been searching for!
                            if( array_key_exists( $key, $models_value ) )
                            {
                                if($col !=NULL)
                                {
                                    if($lots_value[$col] == $cond)
                                    {
                                        $total += $models_value[$key];
                                        $count ++;
                                    }
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    $total += $models_value[$key];
                                    $count ++;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
    return $total / $count;
}
```